# For loop with two variables using zip, still too many values to unpack

Tags: python-2.x

I have two lists, one of which a set of row numbers and another that is .csv file paths. I need to create a loop which will create new dataframes for each file path with the row number I specify.

I have script which creates the new dataframes however I am stuck on the loop.

I have tried using zip for each variable, however I still get too many values to unpack

```
MYLIST = [42, 50, 52, 59, 60, 62]

ID = '/Users/uni/Desktop/corrindex+id/rt35'


for X,Y in zip(ID,MYLIST):
    df= pd.read_csv(X,
                 index_col= False,
                 header=None,
                 nrows=max(my_list) + 1).loc[Y], engine = 'python'
```

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

This is the error I'm receiving, I'm at a loss as to why.

Comment: You should provide stack trace. Also, I recommend you to print `list(zip(ID, MYLIST))`, the result might surprise you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm unsure what stack trace is. I'm still a beginner